# .jar integration in python

Tags: java, python, jar, integration

I am accessing a java jar in my python program to get metadata of images.I have around 90000 images in my folder.For each images I need to use the jar and get data from it.Currently I have coded as below which work completely file for 10 images.But it is really slow when I have a lot of images.My code is as follows

```
def jarWrapper(*args):
    process = Popen(['java', '-jar']+list(args), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    ret = []
    while process.poll() is None:
        line = process.stdout.readline()
        if line != '' and line.endswith('\n'):
            ret.append(line[:-1])
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
    ret += stdout.split('\n')
    if stderr != '':
        ret += stderr.split('\n')
    ret.remove('')
    return re

def main():
    listofkeys =['Content-Length','Image Height','Image Width']
    hashvaludict ={}

    for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk('/Users/akira/Documents/LiClipseWorkspace/cnf/duplicate_image'):

        files = [fi for fi in files if not fi.startswith(".DS_Store")]
        files = sorted(files)
        for filename in files:
            listofcontentvalue =[]
            args = ['/Users/akira/tika-app-1.10.jar','-m' ]
            args.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
            #print args
            result = jarWrapper(*args)

main()
```

Please suggest me a way in which I can make this process faster.

Comment: Have you profiled the code to see where it is slow?

Comment: Maybe you should (if possible) do everything with java, you would "win" the java app "warmup"

Comment: I need to do it in python only.

Comment: ..or perhaps use PIL/Pillow (http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/) if that can get you the information you're looking for..?

Comment: I need to use this jar only to get the metadata.is there any other way execute jar from python script?

Comment: well..., your `jarWrapper` function does a lot of stuff that doesn't really make sense to me. Perhaps if you show us the output of the command, and what you want `jarWrapper` to return..?

Comment: output looks like as follows['Component 1: Y component: Quantization table 0, Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert', 'Component 2: Cb component: Quantization table 1, Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert', 'Component 3: Cr component: Quantization table 1, Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert', 'Compression Type: Progressive, Huffman', 'Content-Length: 14312', 'Content-Type: image/jpeg', 'Data Precision: 8 bits', 'File Modified Date: Sun Oct 04 16:08:27 PDT 2015']

Comment: edit your question instead of putting new info in comment..

Comment: my problem is each 20000 images uses the jar file one at a time.So its taking time.

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/chrismattmann/tika-python ?